# Can I see the history of requests in SQLworkbenchJ?

Tags: sql, sql-workbench-j

Is there a way to retrieve the history of requests, like its done in Psequel for example ?

Comment: damn,! my VM died and I just converted a HUGE query into redshift syntax in there from mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "WbHistory" statement in your tab. It lists sql statements for that tab.

See the [the manual](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/wb-commands.html#command-history)